# Why isn't this [Int]-Element of type 'Int'?

Tags: swift

I tried to write just a simple Bubble-Sort function:

```
func bubbleSort(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    while !isSorted(array) {
        for index in 1..<array.count {
            if array[index - 1] > array[index] {                
                let temp: Int = array[index]
                array[index] = array[index - 1]
                array[index - 1] = temp
            }
        }
    }

    return array
}
```

To check, when the array is sorted it uses:

```
func isSorted(array: [Int]) -> Bool {
    for index in 1..<array.count {
        if array[index - 1] > array[index] {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

I used http://swiftstub.com/ to compile the code, but it gave me following error-message:

```
<stdin>:17:17: error: '@lvalue $T11' is not identical to 'Int'
array[index] = array[index - 1]
^
<stdin>:18:17: error: '@lvalue $T8' is not identical to 'Int'
array[index - 1] = temp
^
```

(If you want to check it out on the site: http://swiftstub.com/385904096/)

---

How can `array[index]` and `array[index - 1]` not both be of type `Int`, and how could they even be of different types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the array passed to the function is immutable. In order to make it mutable, you have to pass it by reference by using the `inout` modifier:

```
func bubbleSort(inout array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
```

note that when using `inout`, you have to pass the corresponding parameter as a reference using the `&` operator when invoking the function:

```
let res = bubbleSort(&myArray)
```

Also note that to swap 2 variables, you can just use:

```
swap(&array[index], &array[index - 1])
```

Suggested reading: [In-Out Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_267)

Comment: Doesn't that pass the array by reference then, meaning that it would change the original version of the array?

Comment: You have to use the `&` operator - read updated answer, but also read linked documentation

Comment: Well, exactly...
Let's assume I didn't want to pass the array by reference, so that the original version isn't changed. How would I do that?

Comment: @445646: `func bubbleSort(var array: [Int]) -> [Int]`

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. `var` makes the parameter mutable, but of course that's just a copy. So the original array passed to the function is not affected by any change made inside the func body.

Comment: Are parameters always passed in a constant/immutable way?
Would myFunc(myInt) pass myInt as immutable?

Comment: Yes they are immutable. Note that in case of reference types (i.e. instance of classes), the reference itself is immutable, not the instance it points to.